# How to use assumed-shape explicit-length character arrays as dummy argument with ifort?

Tags: arrays, compiler-errors, fortran, intel, gfortran

Recently I stumbled across the following issue when switching from `gfortran` (gcc 9.3) to `ifort` (intel 19.2) (changing from local machine to cluster).

Reducing it to a MWE revealed the passing of an *assumed-shape* (:) character array to a module subroutine. This is the code

```
module mymod
  implicit none

  interface
    module integer function func(arg, l)
      integer :: l
      character(len=l), dimension(:), intent(in) :: arg
    end function
  end interface

end module


submodule (mymod) submod
  implicit none

  contains

    module procedure func
      implicit none
      func = size(arg)
    end procedure

end submodule


program myprog
  use mymod
  implicit none
  write(*,*) func(["xy", "ab", "ij"], 2)
end program
```

And this is the error thrown by `ifort`:

```
myprog.f90: catastrophic error: **Internal compiler error: segmentation violation signal raised** Please report this error along with the circumstances in which it occurred in a Software Problem Report.  Note: File and line given may not be explicit cause of this error.
compilation aborted for myprog.f90 (code 1)
```

The original intent of my function is obviously something different and a bit more complex, but the concept is the same since it would require the `size()` intrinsic to be available for `arg` (or `lbound` and `ubound`).

## Stuff making the error go away and maintain the purpose

1. using an `assumed-length` + `assumed-shape` dummy argument:

   ```
   module integer function func(arg)
       character(len=*), dimension(:), intent(in) :: arg
   end function
   ```

   Works with an allocatable character variable as argument in `func()` and with the constructor. This is my favourite solution since I can drop the `l` which I really didn't need in the first place.
2. not using an interfaced `module function` and submodule with the `module procedure` but an internal function in the module `mymod`s `contains` section
3. using `assumed-length` and `assumed-shape` + `allocatable` in the dummy argument

   ```
   character(len=:), dimension(:), allocatable, intent(in) :: arg
   ```

   which requires a likewise allocatable variable to be used when calling `func` (instead of the constructor expression of the example, which might or might not proove to be annoying)

## Stuff making the error go away but are not an option

1. switching to `assumed-size` instead of `assumed-shape`:
   `character(len=l), dimension(*)`
   but then `size` intrinsic won't work (yay, a different error, which was to be expected)
2. having an `integer` array instead of `character` (obviously only to check if its the case for any assumed-shape, interfaced module procedure... it's not)

## Stuff not changing the error

1. simply adding `allocatable` to the dummy variable declaration while keeping the defined length `len=l` part (and using an allocatable variable as argument when calling `func`)

As the code works with the adjustment of `(len=*)` (making it no longer an deferred length character which is fine by me) my main question concernes the different behaviours of the compilers.

**Is it *right* that `gfortran` compiles this and the program behaves as intended — making this a bug in `ifort` — or is it wrong that `gfortran` does this?**

Comment: Whether the compiler should reject the code or not, that an _internal compiler error_ was raised means that this is a bug. Intel specifically requests in the message that it be reported.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a compiler bug that the compiler vendor asks be reported in its error message; workarounds have already been identified in the question.

Comment: Internal compiler error is always a problem inside the compiler. Therefore your question has a trivial answer, it is a bug in ifort and the error message says so.